# compare strings of columns and sport differences

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains strings in this format and more. This is how the table looks like:

```
x <- data.frame("v1_old" = c("[is_minimum] = '0'", "[is_minimum] = '0'"),
                "v1_new" = c("[is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'", "[is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1'"))
```

Now I am comparing the two columns and spotting differences within the strings of each row then be able to create a new column with suffix **_diff** meaning differences.

Now I have tried with this first code
**CODE1:**

```
df <- data.frame(x)
old_cols <- grep("old$", names(df), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- grep("new$", names(df), value = TRUE)

df[sub("new$", "diff", new_cols)] <- Map(stringr::str_remove, 
                                         df[new_cols], df[old_cols])
```

and this is the result I get with this code
**RESULT1**

```
result <- data.frame("v1_old" = c("[is_minimum] = '0'", "[is_minimum] = '0'"),
                "v1_new" = c("[is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'", "[is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1'"),
                "v1_diff" = c ("[is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'", "[is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1'"))
```

This is not the result I expect. I want the diff column to only have that part which doesnt exist between the two column comparison.

Now I have this code which gives me the right result but the problem is I have to keep manually changing column names to get the result. Its not efficient, I expect same result but automate column selection. My question is how can I automate this code to work like first one and give me same result. This is the code and result
**CODE2**

```
x$v1_diff<- mapply(function(x, y) paste(setdiff(y, x), collapse = '| '), strsplit(x$v1_old, '\\||, | | -| \\+'), strsplit(x$v1_new, '\\||, | | -| \\+'))
```

result for this code is:
**RESULT2**

```
result2 <- data.frame("v1_old" = c("[is_minimum] = '0'", "[is_minimum] = '0'"),
                "v1_new" = c("[is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'", "[is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1'"),
                "v1_diff" = c (" and| '1'", "and| [t_sheet]| ='1'"))
```

The second result is what I expect but as you see with second code I have to keep changing column names manually but with the first code I don't. How can I automate second code or alter it to look like first code but give same output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have multiple pairs of `old` and `new`. This may not be the most elegant solution but it works

```
x2 = setNames(cbind(x,x),c("v1_old","v1_new","v2_old","v2_new"))              
res = sapply(seq(1,ncol(x2)/2,2),function(k){mapply(function(x, y) paste(setdiff(y, x), collapse = '| '), strsplit(x2[,k], '\\||, | | -| \\+'), strsplit(x2[,k+1], '\\||, | | -| \\+'))})

res2 = cbind(x2,setNames(as.data.frame(res,stringsAsFactors = FALSE),c(paste0("v",1:ncol(res),"_diff"))))              

res2_ord = res2[,order(gsub("v([0-9]+).*","\\1",names(res2)))] 
res2_ord
              v1_old                                    v1_new              v1_diff             v2_old
1 [is_minimum] = '0' [is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'             and| '1' [is_minimum] = '0'
2 [is_minimum] = '0'     [is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1' and| [t_sheet]| ='1' [is_minimum] = '0'
                                     v2_new              v2_diff
1 [is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'             and| '1'
2     [is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1' and| [t_sheet]| ='1'
```

**code explanation**
I first created `x2`, which has two pairings. Then, for each pairing we run your provided code. This generates a matrix `res2` which we name accordingly. Then, we reorder it by taking into account only the number found in the name.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to split and use `setdiff` to find different words. Use `paste` to convert them to strings, i.e.

```
i1 <- lapply(x, strsplit, ' ')
mapply(function(x, y)paste(setdiff(x, y), collapse = ' | '), i1[[2]], i1[[1]])

#[1] "and | '1'"              "and | [t_sheet] | ='1'"
```

You can then assign it back to your data frame, i.e.

```
x$v2_diff <- mapply(function(x, y)paste(setdiff(x, y), collapse = ' | '), i1[[2]], i1[[1]])
```

Comment: good answer, how can I have your Code generate same table output. I am just getting strings sir

Comment: I like the output but now what if I have multiple columns which are different by name but still have suffixes old and new? I see you code you have specified v2_diff but what if I am comparing multiple pairs of columns with same dataframe and I do what to generate diff column automatically

Comment: One way is to use `split.default` to split your data frame to the columns you want and apply the methodology I provided above to all elements. If you add an example I will be able to show you how.